# I do not understand why this code would not open a file

Tags: c++, file, qt, user-interface, qfile

I can not figure out why this code would not open a file please help. I have tried many different things but nothing works. I do not believe it even opens the file?

this is the main.cpp

```
#include "communicate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Communicate window;

  window.setWindowTitle("Communicate");
  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

this is my header.

```
using namespace std;
class Communicate : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT

  public:
   Communicate(QWidget *parent = 0);


  //private slots:
  //void onenter();
  //void OnMinus();

  private:
    QFile namefile;
    QTextStream file;
    QString name;
    QLabel *label;
    QTextEdit *left;
    QTextEdit *right;
    QLineEdit *user;



};

#endif
```

this is the main window.cpp

```
#include "communicate.h"
Communicate::Communicate(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),namefile("pname.txt"),file(&namefile)
{

  QPushButton *enter = new QPushButton("enter", this);
  enter->setGeometry(205, 205, 90, 35);

  //QPushButton *minus = new QPushButton("-", this);
  //minus->setGeometry(50, 100, 75, 30);

  label = new QLabel("money: 500", this);
  label->setGeometry(105, 0, 90, 30);

  left = new QTextEdit(this);
  left ->setGeometry(0,0,100,200);

  right = new QTextEdit(this);
  right ->setGeometry(200,0,100,200);   

  user = new QLineEdit(this);
  user ->move(0,205);
  user ->resize(200,35);

  name=file.readLine();
  right->setText(name);
  label->setText(name);
  namefile.close();
  //connect(enter, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onenter()));
  //connect(minus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnMinus()));
```

}

Comment: How is it supposed to know that it should open a file? I see a call to `close()` at the end of your code, but not a single call to `open()`.

Comment: You're exactly right, though it's not really so much about knowing _whether_ to open the file as much as it's about _how_ to open the file. That is, is it reading? Writing? Truncating? Appending? Text?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't open the file. You must open the file yourself, then create your `QTextStream` and pass it the opened file. Like this:

```
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
     return;

 QTextStream in(&file);
 name = file.readLine();
```

Your textstream needn't be a class member since you're only using it in the constructor. You can read all about using `QFile` and `QTextStream` here. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html

Comment: OK thanks that helps but I think I do need it as a class member because I will use it in other functions.

Comment: I can understand that. I would, however, suggest that you're giving this class too many responsibilities. Unless this is just a one-off project to try out new things or to test or whatever, I'd move the file opening and reading responsibilities somewhere else. Consider the Model/View/Controller pattern, or some other way of separating responsibilities.